# ElasticSearch search through an array field as exclusive search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I do have an array of data in a field in ElasticSearch with a keyword type. I want to search this array with exclusive values that I want to search i.e. to exclude array values thats not included in my search keyword. Please see the details below.

Thanks!

I have the following elastic search index mapping:

```
"exgroups": {
  "type": "keyword",
  "eager_global_ordinals": true
},
```

With the following sample data:

```
"id": 1,
"exgroups": ["TSX"]

"id": 2,
"exgroups": ["TSX", "OTC", "NSD"]
```

My search is like this:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "filter" : {

        "term" : {
          "exgroups" : {
            "value" : "TSX"
          }
        }

    }
  }
}
```

I've used MatchQueryBuilder, TermQueryBuilder, TermsQueryBuilder to no avail. By the ElasticSearch TermQuery definition, it should do the trick. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-term-query.html. But it does not, probably because the field is an array.

In general, the Term*Query behaves like this:

```
iterate all the documents, for each document
  check if the exgroups contains 'tsx'
  if it does, return the document
```

This returns documents 1 and 2 since document 2 contains TSX also. However, I wanted for it to return *only* document 1 and no other else in the array.

How do I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Re-index solution:**

I recently found this documentation from ElasticSearch:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html

Both TermQuery and TermsQuery or ElasticSearch in general uses the 'must contain' rather than the 'must equals to' because of its inverted index.

According to them, the best solution possible is:

> If you do want that behavior—entire field equality—the best way to accomplish it involves indexing a secondary field. In this field, you index the number of values that your field contains. Using our two previous documents. Once you have the count information indexed, you can construct a constant_score that enforces the appropriate number of terms. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html#_equals_exactly

Steps below:

1. Add additional mapping in the index called exgroups_count.
2. Use logstash to count the exgroups array length and put into the exgroups_count field.
3. save the index.

### **Another Solution without Re-index:**

There are some limitations of adding and re-indexing the whole thing. Once your index is growing, it will be very intrusive adding fields to the index, and computing the counts - making it very operation intensive - not to mention you have to save and maintain your mapping.

I found a solution that has no need of re-index. Looking at the ScriptQueryBuilder, I can be able to theoretically add a script filter that counts the length of the array and equate to 1.

```
"filter" : {
    "script" : {
        "script" : "doc['exgroups'].values.length == 1"
    }
}
```

So the full query becomes now likes this:

```
"bool" : {
  "must" : [
    {
      "term" : {
        "exgroups" : {
          "value" : "TSX",
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "filter" : [
    {
      "script" : {
        "script" : {
          "source" : "doc['exgroups'].values.length == 1",
          "lang" : "painless"
        },
        "boost" : 1.0
      }
    }
  ],
  "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
  "boost" : 1.0
}
```

In Java,

```
BoolQueryBuilder qBool = new BoolQueryBuilder();
TermQueryBuilder query = new TermQueryBuilder("exgroups", exchangeGroup.getCode());

qBool.must(query);

ScriptQueryBuilder sQuery = new ScriptQueryBuilder(new Script("doc['exgroups'].values.length == 1"));

qBool.filter(sQuery);
```